# Problem with checking deck for held card. C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, sorting, object

I'm very new and attempting to create a deck that will be filled at random from cardpool, permterm will also be filled with the same cards. This will give you duplicates of some cards and singles of others, as intended. Then you can use a card or draw a card and it will sort hand() and deckArr() correctly.

The problem comes when you draw and use a card back to back. When a card is in your hand, the corresponding trigger in cardActivation will turn to 1. (Meaning it's in your hand and cannot be drawn again) So if you draw, it handles the activation for that one card and shifts the deck accordingly. If you use the card, it is the opposite. It will turn the trigger to 0 (Meaning its available to draw and inside the deck) and shift the hand accordingly.

It seems that it randomly decides not to run the if statement within draw() [if (cardActivation[x] == 0 && hand[handSize-1] == permterm[x])] and will not trigger the activation, thus throwing off the rest of the program, but the next iteration of the loop correctly runs the if statement. When I get to the end of all the testing the activation is off by 1 because of the one time it missed the if statement. (There should be nine 1s instead of eight.)

I've fiddled and changed my code 100000 times but can't figure out why randomly it decided to skip the if statement, as far as I can tell it should still be true.

I've left my notes and tests within my code so hopefully it can help others understand my thinking process, sorry it's such a mess. It was MUCH cleaner before I started bug fixing. The HP bar information can be ignored, it's apart of something else. Hopefully I explained well enough for some help, I'm losing my mind. Thank you in advance!

````
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class healthBar
{
    private:
    int hp;
    
    public: 
    
        healthBar()
        {
            hp = 100;
        }
        int damage(int dmg)
        {
            hp-=dmg;
            if (hp == 0)
            {
                cout << "Youve Died " << endl;
                resetHP();
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                printHP();
                return 1;
            }
        }
        void heal(int regen)
        {
            hp+=regen;
        }
        void printHP()
        {
            cout << "HP is: " << hp << endl;
        }
        void resetHP()
        {
            hp = 100;
        }
};
class myDeck
{
    private:
    int deckArr[30];
    int tempDeck[30];
    int permterm[30];
    int hand[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    int handSize = 0;
    int cardPool[25] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
    , 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25};
    int cardActivation[30];
    public:
    myDeck()
    {
        //Attaches Deck
        int x;
        srand(time(0));
        for (int y = 0; y < 30; y++)
        {
            x = rand()%25;
            deckArr[y] = cardPool[x];
            cout << deckArr[y] << endl;
        }
        cout << "Permterm:" << endl;
        for (int z = 0; z < 30; z++)
        {
            permterm[z] = deckArr[z];
            cardActivation[z] = 0;
            cout << permterm[z] << endl;
        }
        /*If you wanted duplicates of cards but 
        also be able to reject if that specific card has
        been drawn already, you'd need an
        activation array lined up with the permterm. 0=Not Active (Dont Skip) 1= In Hand (Skip) 
        It will need to search for the number.*/
    }
    void shuffle()
    {
        int z = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x<30; x++)
        {
            tempDeck[x] = deckArr[x];
        }
        srand(time(0));
        int y;
        for (int x = 0; x<30; x++)
        {
            y = rand()%30;
            if (y != z)
            {
                deckArr[x] = tempDeck[y];
            }
            z = y;
        }
        cout << "\nShuffled!" << endl;
    }
    void drawHand()
    {
        handSize=7;
        for (int x = 0; x < 7; x++)
        {
            hand[x] = deckArr[x];
        
        }
        for (int x = 0; x<30; x++)
        {
            deckArr[x] = deckArr[x+7];
        }
        for (int x = 23; x < 30; x++)
        {
            deckArr[x] = 0;
        }
            //Switch On and Search
            for (int y = 0; y < handSize; y++)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
                {
                    if (hand[y] == permterm[x] && cardActivation[x] == 0)
                    {
                            cardActivation[x] = 1;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        cout << "\nHand Drawn!" << endl;
    }
    void viewDeck()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x<30; x++)
        {
            cout << permterm[x] << "       " << cardActivation[x] << endl;
        }
    }
    void viewHand()
    {
        for (int x = 0; x<handSize; x++)
        {
            cout << hand[x] << endl;
        }
    }
    void resetDeck()
    {
        int resetCard;
        int handTemp = handSize;
        for (int y = 0; y < 30-handTemp; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x<30;x++)
            {
                if (cardActivation[x] != 1)
                {
                    deckArr[y] = permterm[x];
                    break;
                    
                }
            }
        }
        
        cout << "Reset!"<< endl;
    }
    void draw()
    {
        if (handSize < 10)
        {
            cout << "\nDrawing..." << endl;
            hand[handSize] = deckArr[0];
            cout << "You drew: " << deckArr[0] << endl;
            handSize++; 
             for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
            {
                deckArr[x] = deckArr[x+1];
            }
            deckArr[29] = 0;
            //Activation
            for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
                {
                    if (cardActivation[x] == 0 && hand[handSize-1] == permterm[x])
                    {
                        cardActivation[x] = 1;
                        viewDeck();
                        break;
                    }
                }
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\nYour hand is full!" << endl;
        }
        //Test to see if deck needs to be reset
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
        {
            sum+=deckArr[x];
        }
        
        //Checks to see if sending to resetDeck.
        if (sum == 0)
        {
            viewDeck();
            resetDeck();
        }
    }
    void useCard()
    {
        int input;
        cout << "\nWhich card would you like to use?" << endl;
        for (int y = 0; y < handSize; y++)
        {
            cout << y+1 << ". " << hand[y] << endl;
        }
        cin >> input;
        cout << "\nYou used: " << hand[input-1] << endl;
        //Deactivate
        for (int x = 0; x < 30; x++)
        {
                    if (cardActivation[x] == 1 && hand[input-1] == permterm[x])
                    {
                        cardActivation[x] = 0;
                        break;
                    }
        }
        viewDeck();
        for (int y = input-1; y<handSize; y++)
        {
                        if (y+1 == 10)
                        {
                            hand[y] = 0;
                        }
                        else
                           hand[y] = hand[y+1];
        }
    handSize--; 
    
    }
};

int main()
{
    /*Objective: Create a game where you draw from a deck of cards, to have 7 cards in hand.*/
    healthBar health;
    myDeck deck;
    deck.viewDeck();
    cout << "\nShuffling..." << endl;
    deck.shuffle();
    deck.viewDeck();
    cout << "\nDrawing Hand..." << endl;
    deck.drawHand();
    deck.viewHand();
        cout << "\nIs the Deck missing 7 cards?" << endl;
    deck.viewDeck();
    cout << "Can you draw? Hand:" << endl;
    deck.draw();
    deck.viewHand();
    cout << "\nIs the deck missing 8 cards?" << endl;    deck.viewDeck();
    cout << "\nCan you draw until hand is full?" << endl;
    deck.draw();
    deck.viewHand();
    deck.draw();
    deck.viewHand();
    deck.draw();
    deck.viewHand();
    cout << "\nCan you use a card?" << endl;
    deck.useCard();
    deck.draw();
    deck.useCard();
    deck.draw();
    deck.useCard();
    deck.draw();
    deck.useCard();
    for (int x = 0; x <10; x++)
    {
        deck.draw();
        deck.useCard();
    }
    
    cout << "\nDoes resetting exclude your hand?" << endl;
    cout << "Hand: " << endl;
    deck.viewHand();
    cout << "Deck: " << endl;
    deck.viewDeck();```
````

Comment: Hi Matthew.  I have to admit this looks a lot like a homework problem.  StackOverflow isn't a code-review website -- the goal here is provide solutions to problems that many people might have -- so please keep that in mind.  But even so, I'd like to help.  The problem comes in even understanding how this is supposed to work.  That's why SO has guidelines about providing a minimal, reproducible example:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.    Now I realize that's not always possible but when I run your app it's difficult to see what the problem is.

Comment: It's not homework. I'm learning on my own and had an idea for a simple game. Once I felt I knew enough to make a very basic version, I wanted to start by just getting the deck idea working. After playing with my code more, I found out it's because it's drawing a card that is not available but now that's stumping me. I'm just glad to be on to a slightly different problem

Comment: @MatthewWhite: Can you try to create a [minimal reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?  It helps us get to the problem without reading through a bunch of extra code, and half the time you will figure out the answer on your own in the process of stripping out what's not necessary.

Comment: `for (int x = 0; x<30; x++) { deckArr[x] = deckArr[x+7]; }` exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an index out of bounds. This loop is going all the way up to `deckArr[36]`